# How to prove properties of pre-image of random oracle in zero-knowledge proof?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, random-oracle-model

A signature *Sig* is given as input to random oracle H, such that y = H(*Sig*) and *Sig* should be hidden from the verifier. How to prove in zero-knowledge to the verifier that y is the correct output from a random oracle evaluated on *Sig* which verifies under some public key in a given set of public key while keeping the *Sig* hidden.

Comment: You can't. There's no compact/efficient concrete random oracle. What you can do is prove for a concrete (non-)instantiation (ie any particular hash function) but (structure of) the proof will directly depend on the concrete hash function choosen

Comment: this seems like an answer to me